My Jade is sick Please help
drooping and white spots on stalk. It’s not mold. Had mold a couple weeks ago. Used a small tooth brush to remove

pictures please, a closeup will really help to identify any pests

Succulents are beloved by mealy bugs ... white cottony masses hiding at joints. Can you use alcohol and soap?
